# Are the words 'lawyerly' and 'loyally' homophones in BrE?

Tags: pronunciation, homophones

In American English there is a clear difference, but do the words 'lawyerly' and 'loyally' actually sound the same in British English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will depend *which* British accent. They are homophones in my own south-eastern, non-rhotic accent.

They are not in the rhotic accent where I live (south-west). Which, I assume, is the reason they are not homophones in the USA.

I can't speak for other accents but the vowels may differ in other parts of the country, even if the accent is non-rhotic.

Comment: +1. They’re not homophones in Scotland either. This answer could likely be evidenced by Youglish with a little time and patience if the OP is interested.

Comment: @Pam thank you for introducing me to Youglish.